# How many strings of length n which differ from each other by m or more letters are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Alphabet consists of **M** letters.
Strings may have repeats.

The question is: how many strings of ***n*** letters are there such that every string differs from each other by ***m*** or more letters?

Comment: Can I ask if you've checked the many other similar questions on the site first?

Comment: Certainly I have. Yet I've found nothing similar enough to be useful: I just have too little knowledge in combinatorics to transform them into my case. If a question which describes the same problem in a different manner was already asked and I have missed it, I would appreciate if you point to it.